# Долой ненужную метку, [xor] ^ [xor]!

Tags: предложение, метки, удаление-метки

Предлагаю удалить метку [xor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xor) сразу по нескольким причинам:

1. [По ней задано всего 4 вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xor), один из которых имеет очень шаткое отношение к `xor`'у
2. Метка появилась относительно недавно: все вопросы заданы за период сентябрь 2018 - январь 2019
3. Какой смысл обычному математическому оператору иметь отдельную метку?
4. Да и я бы не сказал, что вопросы с этой меткой на данный момент несут хоть какую-то пользу сообществу

Comment: С другой стороны - вы оформили вопрос на мете, другие участники потратили время на ответы (даже со скриншотами) ради метки, по которой есть всего 4 вопроса. От её удаления что-то станет лучше? Если нет - то зачем тратить время? :)

Comment: @PashaPash лучше уже не будет, всё тлен.

Answer (score 4):

1. Можно выпилить её путём замены на [битовые-операции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8).
2. Или просто синонимизировать метку к [битовые-операции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8).

Comment: Думаю, лучше все же синонимизировать.

Comment: Почему битовые, а не булевы?

Comment: @АндрейNOP каждый бит аргумента в битовых операциях может рассматриваться как булева переменная. Битовые — более общий случай. Но смыслы могут быть разные в вопросах, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

На enSO с вами бы не согласились. [Метка существует с достаточным количеством вопросов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xor) и даже имеет почти пару десятков подписчиков:

> [image: xor tag]

Не очень представляю, что мы выиграем при удалении этой метки или замене на более обобщённую типа «битовые операции».

Comment: enSO - это, конечно, хорошо, но конкретно у нас нет и сотни вопросов за все время существования ресурса. Да и не понимаю, почему тогда не существует меток для логических операций and/or/etc.

Comment: Слишком детализированная метка, как по мне.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker потому что эти метки запрещены даже не через черный список, а на уровне движка. Если попытаться их набрать в поле меток, они испаряются без уведомления. А вот [bitwise-and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitwise-and) на EN SO существует.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker кстати, да, БелыйРыцарь прав. Я даже как-то [вопрос задавал на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298293/339911) об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Метка как метка. Не вижу причин её выпиливать. Разве мешает кому-то?